# Filtering an ng-repeat based on multiple values in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is difficult to phrase but:
I have 1 collection called `users`.
Every user has 3 properies: `id, name, skill`.

```
    {
        _id: 1,
        name: 'frank young',
        skill: 'java'
    },
```

I have 1 form collects search results upon pressing enter.

```
<form ng-submit="pushToNewArry(searchTerm)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchTerm" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

*this is not the best way to do this*

```
$scope.newUsers = [];
$scope.pushToNewArry = function(msg) {
    $scope.trackedUsers.push(msg);
    $scope.searchTerm = '';
};
```

**Question:**

How do I create a filter that will run over multiple search terms and create a list proper matches based on the `users` collections vs inputed values.

```
<ol ng-repeat = "user in users | filter: trackedUsers">
    <li class="names"><span>{{$index}}. </span>{{user.name}}</li>
    <li class="skills">{{user.skill}}</li> 
</ol>
```

Upon submission, the user input will be saved and create a new array of `users` based on inputed values of search.  therefore, multiple matching values.

Updated:

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S4m9A/20/)

*not excatly the same as example above because I keep playing with it.*

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by: `create a list proper matches based on the users collections vs inputed values.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like [this jsfriddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g966216g/2/)

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjc5ppq8/1/)

updated [fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/mjc5ppq8/2/)

```
<div>{{listSearchTerms | json}}</div>
<form ng-submit="saveSearchTerm()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchTerm" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<ol  ng-repeat = "user in users | filter:filterSearch(searchTerm)">
    <li class="names"><span>{{$index}}. </span>{{user.name}}</li>
    <li class="skills">{{user.skill}}</li> 
</ol>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

//App.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//App.factory('myService', function() {});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.users = [
        {
            _id: 1,
            name: 'frank young',
            skill: 'java'
        },
        {
            name: 'jeff qua',
            skill: 'javascript'
        },
        {
            name: 'frank yang',
            skill: 'python'
        },
        {
            name: 'ethan nam',
            skill: 'python'
        },
        {
            name: 'ethan nam',
            skill: 'javascript'
        },
    ];
    $scope.searchTerm = "";
    $scope.listSearchTerms = [];
$scope.filterSearch = function (terms) {
    return function (item) {
        return terms.length < 1 ? true : 
        terms.reduce(function (lastresult, term) {
            return lastresult + (item.name.indexOf(term) > -1 || item.skill.indexOf(term) > -1);
        }, 0) > 0;

    }
};
    $scope.saveSearchTerm = function () {
        $scope.listSearchTerms.push($scope.searchTerm);
        $scope.searchTerm = "";
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes but I would liek to treat this like tags in Stack.  where when you add them those become fixed to the query.  meaning, if i type in javascript and press enter: it will always show people that know javascript.  then if I type in frank and type enter: it will show me all people that know javascript and all people that are named frank.

Comment: Dang wayne super close! but can the second input be filtered from the original users collection and not a filter of the filtered array.  Essentially, if one submits 'python' and 'jeff' to listSearchTerms.  The results will return 3 people: jeff qua (javascript), frank yang(python), ethan nam(python).  Lastly, thanks so much for your help you're a rockstar.